# What is the significance of the default 1982-02-12 17:00:00 timestamp in Core Data?

Tags: xcode, date, core-data

When configuring a Date attribute in Core Data, Xcode will show some default values in the Data Model inspector:

[image: Xcode screenshot]

What is the significance of the timestamp there (1982-02-12 17:00:00), which might or might not be a local time (I'm using CET now, so that would be 16:00 UTC)? The Unix timestamp of these moments (382381200 and 382377600) don't ring a bell. Shifting them 31 years (Core Data [usually counts from 2001-01-01](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/288321/121968)) doesn't produce any insightful values either. Is it some kind of Easter Egg (perhaps one of the Xcode developers was born that day?)

Comment: I do not know where that value comes from. But it seems to be a placeholder and not a real default value. As soon as you select one of the checkboxes, the placeholder is replaced by the *current* date.